# function which returns true is the string is in upper-case using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am reading value from XML.Is their any way to find whether the 
    value is in upper-case(the value is in different language e.g  english,french,spanish etc)
        I want function which will return true if the value is in upper-case else it returns false.

```
<xsl:variable name="mg" select="DreamBone DreamFillets régals aux 
  légumes et au poulet 170 Gramme">
<xsl:if test="function-to-check-string-is-in-upper-case">
    <xsl:value-of select="$mg"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: XSLT 2.0? It has `upper-case()` function, `upper-case($mg) = $mg` is then true if the string is upper case. If XSLT 1.0 then you do not have `upper-case()` but you can _simulate_ it (for ASCII text) with `translate()`.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0.Thanks @AdrianoRepetti your suggestion work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="mg" select="'DreamBone DreamFillets régals aux légumes et au poulet 170 Gramme'"/>
    <xsl:if test="$mg = translate($mg, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ')">
        <xsl:value-of select="$mg"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 2.0** you can use in `test` phrase:

```
$mg = upper-case($mg)
```

Comment: sorry my bad..can you please provide me solution for XSLT 1.0